# Scraping data from Spotify charts

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, spotify

I want to scrape daily top 200 songs from Spotify charts website. I am trying to parse html code of page and trying to get song's artist, name and stream informations. But following code returns nothing. How can I get these informations with the following way?

```
for a in soup.find("div",{"class":"Container-c1ixcy-0 krZEp encore-base-set"}):
    for b in a.findAll("main",{"class":"Main-tbtyrr-0 flXzSu"}):
        for c in b.findAll("div",{"class":"Content-sc-1n5ckz4-0 jyvkLv"}):
            for d in c.findAll("div",{"class":"TableContainer__Container-sc-86p3fa-0 fRKUEz"}):
                print(d)
```

And let say this is the songs list that I want to scrape from it.
https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-tr-daily/2022-09-14

And also this is the html code of the page.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to webscrape that, just use the spotify APIs playlist endpoint and send a request to get the "Weekly Top Songs Global" public playlist which is the same as the one on the website. Link to Python API integration: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#

Comment: I want to get daily top songs, how can I use this API?

Comment: See the link in my first comment to get a few examples how to use the API. The "Top 50-Global" playlist should be updated daily and stores the daily top songs.

Comment: @Oivalf that's a good recommendation, but you shouldn't include the version number in your url. Them the link will always go to the newest version: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io

Comment: @UğurSelimÖzen i add solution with API

Comment: @UgurSelimOzen, here's an explanation for the requests/pandas solution: data in page is pulled down by Javascript, once original HTML loads. You can see this in Dev Tools - Network Tab, if you will filter network requests by `Fethc/XHR` requests. You will see the songs are being pulled down from `Request URL: https://charts-spotify-com-service.spotify.com/public/v0/charts` (Under 'General'). You will also see the requests headers (which usually need to be respected/added to requests headers, otherwise you get errors). You can read JSON resp directly with pandas: `pd.json_normalize(r.json())`.

Comment: (cont'd @UgurSelimOzen): Also usually (not the case here though), a request to an API endpoint can be a POST request, and those have a payload - you can also find that under `Dev tools - Network tab - Payload`. You need to specify that, along with the headers, when making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example link you provided, there aren't 200 songs, but only 50. The following is one way to get those songs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-tr-daily/2022-09-14'
browser.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print("accepted cookies")
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button')
header_to_be_removed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'header[data-testid="charts-header"]')))
browser.execute_script("""
var element = arguments[0];
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
""", header_to_be_removed)
while True:
    try:
        show_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="load-more-entries"]//button')))
        show_more_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        t.sleep(5)
        show_more_button.click()
        print('clicked to show more')
        t.sleep(3)
    except TimeoutException:
        print('all done')
        break
songs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[data-testid="charts-entry-item"]')))
print('we have', len(songs), 'songs')
song_list = []
for song in songs:
    song.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    t.sleep(1)
    title = song.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[class^="Type__TypeElement-"]')
    artist = song.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-testid="artists-names"]')
    song_list.append((artist.text, title.text))
df = pd.DataFrame(song_list, columns = ['Title', 'Artist'])
print(df)
```

This will print out in terminal:

```
no cookie button
clicked to show more
clicked to show more
clicked to show more
clicked to show more
all done
we have 50 songs
```

|  | Title | Artist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bizarrap, | Quevedo: Bzrp Music Sessions, Vol. 52 |
| 1 | Harry Styles | As It Was |
| 2 | Bad Bunny, | Me Porto Bonito |
| 3 | Bad Bunny | Tití Me Preguntó |
| 4 | Manuel Turizo | La Bachata |
| 5 | ROSALÍA | DESPECHÁ |
| 6 | BLACKPINK | Pink Venom |
| 7 | David Guetta, | I'm Good (Blue) |
| 8 | OneRepublic | I Ain't Worried |
| 9 | Bad Bunny | Efecto |
| 10 | Chris Brown | Under The Influence |
| 11 | Steve Lacy | Bad Habit |
| 12 | Bad Bunny, | Ojitos Lindos |
| 13 | Kate Bush | Running Up That Hill (A Deal With God) - 2018 Remaster |
| 14 | Joji | Glimpse of Us |
| 15 | Nicki Minaj | Super Freaky Girl |
| 16 | Bad Bunny | Moscow Mule |
| 17 | Rosa Linn | SNAP |
| 18 | Glass Animals | Heat Waves |
| 19 | KAROL G | PROVENZA |
| 20 | Charlie Puth, | Left and Right (Feat. Jung Kook of BTS) |
| 21 | Harry Styles | Late Night Talking |
| 22 | The Kid LAROI, | STAY (with Justin Bieber) |
| 23 | Tom Odell | Another Love |
| 24 | Central Cee | Doja |
| 25 | Stephen Sanchez | Until I Found You |
| 26 | Bad Bunny | Neverita |
| 27 | Post Malone, | I Like You (A Happier Song) (with Doja Cat) |
| 28 | Lizzo | About Damn Time |
| 29 | Nicky Youre, | Sunroof |
| 30 | Elton John, | Hold Me Closer |
| 31 | Luar La L | Caile |
| 32 | KAROL G, | GATÚBELA |
| 33 | The Weeknd | Die For You |
| 34 | Bad Bunny, | Tarot |
| 35 | James Hype, | Ferrari |
| 36 | Imagine Dragons | Bones |
| 37 | Elton John, | Cold Heart - PNAU Remix |
| 38 | The Neighbourhood | Sweater Weather |
| 39 | Ghost | Mary On A Cross |
| 40 | Shakira, | Te Felicito |
| 41 | Justin Bieber | Ghost |
| 42 | Bad Bunny, | Party |
| 43 | Drake, | Jimmy Cooks (feat. 21 Savage) |
| 44 | Doja Cat | Vegas (From the Original Motion Picture Soundtrack ELVIS) |
| 45 | Camila Cabello, | Bam Bam (feat. Ed Sheeran) |
| 46 | Rauw Alejandro, | LOKERA |
| 47 | Rels B | cómo dormiste? |
| 48 | The Weeknd | Blinding Lights |
| 49 | Arctic Monkeys | 505 |

​
Of course you can get other info like chart ranking, all artists when there are more than one, etc.

Selenium chrome/chromedriver setup is for Linux, you just have to observe the imports and code after defining the browser, to adapt it to your own setup.

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

For selenium docs, visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Answer (score 4):

none selenium solution:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://charts-spotify-com-service.spotify.com/public/v0/charts'
response = requests.get(url)
chart = []
for entry in response.json()['chartEntryViewResponses'][0]['entries']:
    chart.append({
        "Rank": entry['chartEntryData']['currentRank'],
        "Artist": ', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in entry['trackMetadata']['artists']]),
        "TrackName": entry['trackMetadata']['trackName']
    })
df = pd.DataFrame(chart)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Rank                      Artist                                                 TrackName
    1            Bizarrap,Quevedo                     Quevedo: Bzrp Music Sessions, Vol. 52
    2                Harry Styles                                                 As It Was
    3  Bad Bunny,Chencho Corleone                                           Me Porto Bonito
    4                   Bad Bunny                                          Tití Me Preguntó
    5               Manuel Turizo                                                La Bachata
    6                     ROSALÍA                                                  DESPECHÁ
    7                   BLACKPINK                                                Pink Venom
    8     David Guetta,Bebe Rexha                                           I'm Good (Blue)
    9                 OneRepublic                                           I Ain't Worried
   10                   Bad Bunny                                                    Efecto
   11                 Chris Brown                                       Under The Influence
   12                  Steve Lacy                                                 Bad Habit
   13     Bad Bunny,Bomba Estéreo                                             Ojitos Lindos
   14                   Kate Bush    Running Up That Hill (A Deal With God) - 2018 Remaster
   15                        Joji                                             Glimpse of Us
   16                 Nicki Minaj                                         Super Freaky Girl
   17                   Bad Bunny                                               Moscow Mule
   18                   Rosa Linn                                                      SNAP
   19               Glass Animals                                                Heat Waves
   20                     KAROL G                                                  PROVENZA
   21  Charlie Puth,Jung Kook,BTS                   Left and Right (Feat. Jung Kook of BTS)
   22                Harry Styles                                        Late Night Talking
   23 The Kid LAROI,Justin Bieber                                 STAY (with Justin Bieber)
   24                   Tom Odell                                              Another Love
   25                 Central Cee                                                      Doja
   26             Stephen Sanchez                                         Until I Found You
   27                   Bad Bunny                                                  Neverita
   28        Post Malone,Doja Cat               I Like You (A Happier Song) (with Doja Cat)
   29                       Lizzo                                           About Damn Time
   30            Nicky Youre,dazy                                                   Sunroof
   31   Elton John,Britney Spears                                            Hold Me Closer
   32                   Luar La L                                                     Caile
   33               KAROL G,Maldy                                                  GATÚBELA
   34                  The Weeknd                                               Die For You
   35       Bad Bunny,Jhay Cortez                                                     Tarot
   36  James Hype,Miggy Dela Rosa                                                   Ferrari
   37             Imagine Dragons                                                     Bones
   38    Elton John,Dua Lipa,PNAU                                   Cold Heart - PNAU Remix
   39           The Neighbourhood                                           Sweater Weather
   40                       Ghost                                           Mary On A Cross
   41      Shakira,Rauw Alejandro                                               Te Felicito
   42               Justin Bieber                                                     Ghost
   43    Bad Bunny,Rauw Alejandro                                                     Party
   44             Drake,21 Savage                             Jimmy Cooks (feat. 21 Savage)
   45                    Doja Cat Vegas (From the Original Motion Picture Soundtrack ELVIS)
   46   Camila Cabello,Ed Sheeran                                Bam Bam (feat. Ed Sheeran)
   47 Rauw Alejandro,Lyanno,Brray                                                    LOKERA
   48                      Rels B                                            cómo dormiste?
   49                  The Weeknd                                           Blinding Lights
   50              Arctic Monkeys                                                       505
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Sergey K, which documentation did you use to handle this problem, can you share it?

Comment: @UgurSelimOzen only developers tools  inside browser, f12. And found request in network tab